# Python сколько осталось дней,мин,сек от даты до даты

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, datetime

У меня есть две даты: текущая и нового года.

Понятно, что через модуль `datetime` в `Python 3` можно вычитать эти даты и получить новую, но каким образом можно рассчитать количество времени до нового года в секундах, днях, минутах, часах и т. д.

***Пример:***

```py
До нового года: 60 дней 22 часа 45 мин 12 сек.
```

Answer (score 3):

почему бы не посмотреть что получится, если *вычитать эти даты*. 
А получится объект класса timedelta, который и содержит то, что вам надо

```
now = datetime.datetime.today()
NY = datetime.datetime(2020,1,1)
d = NY-now #  str(d)  '83 days, 2:43:10.517807'
mm, ss = divmod(d.seconds, 60)
hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)
print('До нового года: {} дней {} часа {} мин {} сек.'.format(d.days, hh, mm, ss))
# До нового года: 83 дней 2 часа 43 мин 10 сек.
```